# Google maps dosen't work on googleplay

Tags: android, google-maps

My app works good installed from apk-debug and apk-release, but if I upload apk-release on google play map dosen't show up (like api key is invalid)

I set up both SHA-1 keys from debug and realese on google console.

I set up both debug/res/values/google_maps_api.xml and release/res/values/google_maps_api.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to check is "App Signing" enabled in your Google Play Developers Console. Probably yes.

There you have "Upload Certificate" and "App Signing Certificate".
Your existing SHA-1 is probably from "Upload Certificate". Now you just need to add this SHA-1 from "App Signing Certificate" to the Api keys credentials under the existing SHA-1 from "Upload Certificate".

After this, maps should work on all installed devices.

Comment: Yeah, it was about app signing.
Getting sha-1 from google console made it working

Answer (score 0):

There is a SHA1 for debug, a SHA1 for release and a SHA1 signed after release. No one was working. Than I remembered that I changed the name of my APK before I uploaded it. I put all SHA1's with the name of my APk and with the name of my package. Only so my APK works.